# Disable keyboard input wake up

Tags: keyboard, suspend, acpi, wakeup

I want to disable making my laptop wakes up from suspend on keyboard input. I searched a lot and I disabled all devices in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` but it still wakes up when clicking any button. I checked my BIOS settings but I didn't find anything related to suspend or anything.
Here is my `/proc/acpi/wakeup` file :

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P1      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S3    *disabled
EHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC       S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
RP04      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:08:00.0
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PXSX      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:09:00.0
PEG0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.1
PEG2      S4    *disabled
LID0      S3    *enabled
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified this is the output when the computer wakes up? On my case the `XHC` device disabled the internal keyboard, the internal touchpad, the external keyboard and the external mouse (yes, I'm disabling this in a laptop). If you want to know each device what it is, you can run an `lspci` to understand most of this devices what they are.